# Update function works consistently on PC but not mobile

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to call two functions after 60 seconds:

1. ShowTextBox();
2. Instantiate();

Both functions run on pc after 60 seconds, but on Android, the Instantiate function only gets called every *two* minutes. The ShowTextBox function will still get called every minute, but I want *both* functions to get called every minute, just like they do on pc.

This is my code:

```
private void Update()
{
    apiCheckCountdown += Time.deltaTime;

    if (apiCheckCountdown >= 60f)
    {
        ShowTextBox();
        Instantiate(Platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        apiCheckCountdown = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you build and play on Android?

Comment: from your code there is no way how `ShowTextBox` should be called but `Instantiate` not. They are either called at the same frame or both skipped. I don't know if it helps but what does `ShowTextBox` do?

Comment: No there are no errors, in the code.

Comment: ShowTextBox shows the coins player has, temporarily I've created another countdown for Instantiate and multiplied the addition with 2. 
P.S Does Async Task has anything to do with late instantiation ?